# Changing proportion table values into percentages

Tags: r

I have the following table code

```
weather<-cbind(c(rep("rain",50),rep("sun",70),rep("rain",100),rep("sun",80)))
prop.table(table(weather))
```

...which results in the following output:

```
rain  sun 
 0.5  0.5
```

How can I change the code so that the output instead becomes this:

```
rain  sun 
 50%  50%
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `sprintf` for this. In your example, you would do this:

```
sprintf("%2d%%", prop.table(table(weather))*100)
```

For more number format options, check out the `sprintf` documentation [here](http://www.inside-r.org/r-doc/base/sprintf).

Answer (score 2):

```
paste0(round(prop.table(table(weather))*100, 1),'%')
```

`round` isn't necessary here, but it would be if your values had lots of decimal places.